# Ant concat exclude directory

Tags: ant, concatenation

My application folder structure looks like this...

```
-js
    -libs
        -jquery.js
        -jquery-ui.js
    -app.js
    -ui.js
```

I wish to concatenate the .js files that are in the /js directory but not those in the /js/libs directory. I am using the following code, but it is ignoring the exclude statement:

```
<concat destfile="${build.dir}/js/foot-${build.major}-${build.minor}.concat.js">
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}/js">
    <exclude name="**/libs/**" />
    </fileset>
</concat>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<fileset>` should specify both include and exclude patterns. In addition, it may be good to specify a destination directory for `<concat>` separate from the `<fileset>` input directory.

```
<target name="concat-test">
  <concat destfile="${basedir}/concat.js" fixlastline="yes">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/js">
      <include name="**/*.js" />
      <exclude name="**/libs/**" />
    </fileset>
  </concat>
</target>
```